# Profile creation and how user opt "yes" or "no"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apps

I have **created a procedure(send_csv_report)** which will sent a mail at 12 pm everyday to all those group of employees to whom I want to send. But , now I want that I don't have to  send mail to every employees rather than **I will create a profile and those employees who are interested** **to receive mail will opt for "yes" otherwise "no"** and accordingly they will receive the mail.
So, how I can do this from backend ?

Any efforts/help done will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

save the emails of those opt for "yes" in a table, your stored procedure will read them out to send email. you can create an APEX application on top of your oracle database to provide a GUI form for user to opt for yes or no. Just my 2 cents